# How to set global dynamic variables in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to set global variables in Laravel that I can modify whenever I want. Suppose that I have an admin area where I want to be able to modify colors, ads ... etc. 
How can I do that, without storing values in the database?

Comment: Use sessions, `session()->set('foo', 'bar')` and `session()->get('foo')`

Comment: You can use in-memory databases like `Redis`, it already has support out of the box in Laravel.

Comment: Is there any other better ways , without storing , updating and retrieving data from database ?

Comment: You could use environment variables as well, and then access them with `getenv()`

Comment: Honestly, based on what you're describing. I think it's the best (and easiest) solution to use a database. Last thing you want to do is deal with issues when you (will eventually) need to clear sessions/cache/redis, etc. I wouldn't overthink it IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `config`.

For the example, I am using `Jenssegers\Agent\Agent` to detect is the client desktop and generate different views and different queries. For that, I have created `config/globalVars.php`:

```
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
$agent = new Agent();

return [
    'isDesktop' => $agent->isDesktop()
];
```

Now, I can use `config('globalVars.isMobile')` everywhere.

In your case, you want and to change these vars:

```
    var_dump(config('globalVars.isDesktop')); // true/false

    config(['globalVars' => ['isDesktop' => 'fake info']]);

    var_dump(config('globalVars.isDesktop')); // fake info
```